# About the sentence of Swear blind

Tags: idioms, sentence-structure

> He swore blind that he hadn't taken the money.

I have already learnt that it is a set phrase, but what does 'that clause' modify in the sentence? I think the what should be the 'blind' because the bline looks like the object of the verb 'swore'.

Answer (score 1):

**That he hadn't taken the money** modifies what he swore, which is basically a pledge or a promise. Because it's a set phrase, it doesn't really follow the ordinary rules of grammar, and **blind** is not meant to be taken literally. **Swear blind** means to make a serious pledge of honesty, and **that he hadn't taken the money** modifies this pledge.